# Send Search Results to New Route - React, JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to send my resultsArray data to another route "/search-results". I have been using useNavigate() but by the time the page is showcased the results are not there. It says "no results found" I think it is a time issue, the page is loading faster than the results can populate. Please review my code and help! Thank you!

SearchBar Component:

```
    import { useState } from "react";
    import React from "react";
    import SearchResults from "./SearchResults";
    import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
    import "../../CSS/Search.css";
    import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
    import { faSearch } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
    
    
    //mock data 
    import mockData from "./mockData";
    
    export default function SearchBar() {
        // const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
        const [shoppingResults, setShoppingResults] = useState([]);
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
        const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");
    
        const navigate = useNavigate(); 
    
        const handleSearch = async (e) => {
        //remove this for MVP version
          setLoading(true);
    
            e.preventDefault();
            setSearchInput(e.target.value);
            
    
            //remove this for MVP version
            const filteredResults = mockData.filter(item => item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())
            );
    
            
            setTimeout(() => {
              setShoppingResults(filteredResults);
              setLoading(false);
            }, 1000);
    
        };
        return (
            <div className="search-bar-container">
              <div className="search-bar">
                <input className="search-bar-bar"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Search"
                    value={searchInput}
                    onChange={(e) => setSearchInput(e.target.value)}
                    style={{ textAlign: "center" }}
                />
                <button className="search-button" onClick={handleSearch}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} size="lg" style={{color: "#231a1f",fontSize: "24px", fontWeight: "bold"}} /></button>
              </div>
              <div className="searchResults">
                    {loading ? (
                    <div>Loading...</div>
                     ) : (
                        <SearchResults resultsArray={shoppingResults} />
                     )}
              </div>
              <div className="message">
                  <ul>
                    <li>What's on your list?</li>
                    <li>Start your search above</li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
           
        );
    };
```

SearchResults Component:

```
    import "../../CSS/SearchResults.css"
    // import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
    
    export default function SearchResults({ resultsArray }) {
        return (
            <div className="result-page">
                <div className="results-container">
                {resultsArray ? (
                     resultsArray.map((result, index) => (
                        <div key={index} className="item-containter">
                            <div key={index} className="item-image"><img src={result.thumbnail} alt="Product Thumbnail" /></div>
                            <div key={index} className="item-facts">product rating: {result.rating}</div>
                            <div key={index} className="store-container">
                                <div key={index} className="store-logo"></div>
                                <div className="store-options">
                                {result.title} {result.price}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))
                ):(
                    <div>No results found</div>
                )}
                </div>
            </div>
    
        )
    }
```

Results Page:

```
import SearchResults from "../Components/Searches/SearchResults";

export default function Results() {
    return (
        <div className="search-results">
            <SearchResults />
        </div>
    );
};
```

app.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";

// PAGES
import Home from "./Pages/Home";
import Search from "./Pages/Search";
import Results from "./Pages/Results"


function App() {
  return (

    <div className="App">

      <Router>
         {/* <NavBar /> */}
        <NavBar />
        <main>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Landing />} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About/>} />
            <Route path="/search" element={<Search />} />
            <Route path="/search-results" element={<Results />} />
            <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<LogIn />} />
          </Routes>
        </main>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

landing page:

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "../logo.png";
import "../CSS/Landing.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


function Landing() {
  return (
    <div className="landing-wrapper">
      <div className="header">
        <div className="logo-container">
          <img src={logo} alt="My App Logo" className="logo" />
        </div>
        <div className="links">
          <Link to="/search">Search</Link>
          <Link to="/about">About Us</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p className="centered outlined-text no-margin">Save Time</p>
      <p className="centered big-pink no-margin">Save Money</p>
      <div className="info-box">
        <h3 id="MainText">
        Are you tired of the endless struggle to save money on your grocery shopping? Imagine a world where you can effortlessly compare and contrast prices from various stores, all in one place. Introducing our innovative price comparison website, the ultimate solution to transform your shopping experience.
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div className="buttons">
        <Link to="/register"><button className="register-button">Register</button></Link>
        <Link to="/login"><button className="login-button login">Login</button></Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Landing;
```

Search Page:

```
import SearchBar from "../Components/Searches/SearchBar";
import logo from "../Images/pig-background.png"
import "../CSS/Search.css";


export default function Search() {
    return (
        <div className="search-page-container">
            <div>
                <SearchBar />
            </div>
            <div className="background-img-container">
                <img src={logo} alt="pig logo" />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

SearchBar results are being stored in shoppingResults using the filter method. There is a link from landing page to Search page (SearchBar).

Comment: I don't see anything navigating to a results page from the search page. In fact, the `SearchBar` component is rendering `SearchResults`. Where is `SearchBar` rendered though? Please [edit] to clarify the issue and to include a complete and accurate [mcve].

Comment: am I missing something?  why do you have the function marked async without an await statement

Comment: careful with this as well   setSearchInput(e.target.value);
            // performSearch(searchInput);   due to async nature of useState hook searchInput may not be available here. should prob use  performSearch(e.target.value)

Comment: @Drew Reese, thank you for your reply. I added the Search Page and Landing page to show how Search has a link and how SearchBar is being rendered. I am using the handleChange fxn to get the data from the mockData. The results are being populated to the Search Page after it loads, however, I want the shoppingResults (aka search results) to show on the "/search-results" route. However, I am getting the "or" from the conditional statement in the SearchResults return which is "no results found".

Comment: @BryanDellinger I didn't think I needed the await statement... where should I put it? I am not using the performSearch fxn. I removed it. Also, I don't know how to send the shoppingResults which are the results from filtering the mock data into the route "/search-results". Do you have any idea?

Comment: well if you don't need await then you can remove async from the function.   to pass an array in react router think it is like `<Link
  to="/search-results"
  state={{ yourArray: [1, 2, 3] }}
>`

Comment: Remove rendering `SearchResults` from `SearchBar`, pass `filteredResults` in route state using the `navigate` function, and access the passed route state in `Results` or `SearchResults` from `location.state` via the `useLocation` hook.

Comment: @BryanDellinger I tried that and though I was able to go to "/search-results" route. The data was not passed to it. I received "no results found" Thank you!

Comment: @DrewReese I will try that now, thanks! If it doesn't work I will try useParams().

Comment: The `useParams` hook is for accessing route path params, e.g. `path="/test/:foo"` then you could use `const { foo } = useParams()` in the routed component. If the path value is `"/test/123"` then `foo = "123"`. This won't help you with anything passed in `location.state`.

Comment: Thank you very much @DrewReese! It worked! here is the updated code:

import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const location = useLocation();
  const { filteredResults } = location.state || {};
... 

i took out the SearchResults from the SearchBar, I also removed the shoppingResults state and I add the code above and replaced shoppingResults with filteredResults

Thank you again! I appreciate the help!